# updating selected href value throught the page using jquery

Tags: jquery

update all the href value in a page using jquery.
I have the href="http://www.google.com" coming through out the page and i wanted to update the href mentioning above to be changed to "http://www.test.com" how i can get this done.

Comment: I would like to see more clarification and details here as your wording does not provide a complete understanding of your desired behavior.

Comment: This might be better accomplished using an outbound URL rewriting rule, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[href]').each(function () {
  $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.test.com');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href*="google"]').attr('href', 'http://www.test.com');
```

The selector will go through all links that have `google` somewhere in their `href` attribute with `*=` and if so, it will update their attribute accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Save this as an .html file for a complete working example!

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[href*='http://www.google.com']").attr('href','http://www.test.com').html('Test.com');
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
     <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
     <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
     <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
     <a href="http://www.NotGoogle.com">Not Google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use selectors

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("a[href*='http://www.google.com']").attr('href','http://www.test.com');
</script>
```